# no page break in rdlc report

Tags: rdlc

Currently I have page breaks in my report, I have to click the "next page" button every time to see next page of the report in my browser.

I want to see output of my rdlc report as a continuous report, not page by page. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In your report design, add a rectangle and make sure it's PageBreakAtEnd and PageBreakAtStart properties are both set to false.
Then create all your report items within the rectangle. It should render smoothly without the page breaks.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, if you have a group then just add the details in group row, this will display all the details in a single page in a report.

If you don't have group then just create the group with some distinct data and add the details here instead of details row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Paper Size` in report properties to `Custom` and specify `Width` and `Height` explicitly according to your layout. Then only the report will be rendered in one page.

Answer (score 0):

And if you do it by using Rectangle as its been advised by Nick Masso don't forget to enable "Keep contents together on single page if possible"